# Local config file

Tags: android

Is it possible to read a local file which won't be deleted once the app is uninstalled and without asking for a permission by the user?

I would like to have a configuration file which will allow the debug build app to modify some preferences right during the first start based on some local settings. The file should persist reinstallation of the app.

I've tried to use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` and read the file in Downloads directory, but it does not list a file I've uploaded to the device.

EDIT: I need something without any user interaction as I want to modify some settings during first start and even during the splash screen, just on my testing devices. I would like to use it just for the debug builds on my testing devices. Each device may have different config file and the app will preconfigure itself right after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to read a local file which won't be deleted once the app is uninstalled and without asking for a permission by the user?

You are welcome to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` and allow the user to choose a document. Whether that document is a local file or resides on cloud storage is up to the user, but that would not matter in terms of how you access its content (`ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but in fact I need something without the user's interaction as I want to modify some settings during first start and even during the splash screen, just on my testing device. Currently I just use raw asset file, but sometimes I would like to have the option to modify the config file without rebuild and reinstall.